# regex doesnt stop on matching negation expression

Tags: regex

Trying to build a regex that will match one or other strings except if a 3rd string is matched.

e.g. 
1. no match if string has 'never'
2. else match if string contains 'disappointed' OR 'unhappy'.

I tried using 
(?!(never).$)((disappointed)|(unhappy)).*

Problem is - it doesnt catch the negation (#1 above). i.e. it matches all 3 below while it should have only matched 2 and 3 below.

never disappointed

very disappointed

unhappy disappointed

Comment: what is the programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!.*never).*(disappointed|unhappy).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VPrWPc/2).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*never)`  - no `never` substring can appear after any 0+ chars other than line break (if a DOTALL modifier is used, any chars)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break
- `(disappointed|unhappy)` - either of the two literal char sequences
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break